# Why cmake is looking for default Boost version?

Tags: ros, catkin, boost, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed latest Boost library `1.80.0` from source on Ubuntu `20.04`, then I tried to install the [abb_robot_driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver), but I have got this Error:

```
 Errors     << abb_robot_cpp_utilities:make /home/belal/ros1_ws/pacbot_ws/logs/abb_robot_cpp_utilities/build.make.000.log                                                    
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.71.0', needed by '/home/belal/ros1_ws/pacbot_ws/devel/.private/abb_robot_cpp_utilities/lib/libabb_robot_cpp_utilities.so'.  
Stop.
```

Can you please tell me how can I tell CMake and Catkin that My Boost is `1.81.0` and not the default `1.71.0`, and my libraries folder is `/usr/local/lib/` and not `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`? thanks in advance.

Note that I have added `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib`  to my `~/.bashrc` and I have already done `$ sudo ldconfig`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412255/why-cmake-is-looking-for-default-boost-version?/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2023-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-02-07**:
I've updated the title of your question, as this is a CMake question. Catkin is not involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will likely not do anything. That's a runtime setting.

This is purely a "CMake thing". According to the [FindBoost.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html#hints) documentation:

> This module reads hints about search locations from variables:
>
> - `BOOST_ROOT`, `BOOSTROOT`
>
>   Preferred installation prefix.

You should be able to do something like:

```
catkin_make [all your other args] --cmake-args -DBOOST_ROOT:PATHNAME=/path/to/your/boost
```

This might or might not work, depending on whether the package(s) you're trying to build are the first to look for Boost. If one of the dependencies have already done that, and the result gets cached or exported, your dependents will most likely not evaluate `FindBoost` again, leading to your `BOOST_ROOT` being ignored.

**But** in all cases: please be aware that mixing different Boost versions is fraught with potential problems.

Mostly `SEGFAULT`s.

You cannot link a ROS node to multiple versions of Boost, which is what will happen when you link `abb_robot_driver`'s nodes against `roscpp` (which it must) and your custom Boost version.

Unless you've built the whole of your ROS Noetic from source with that specific Boost version, I wouldn't recommend doing what you're trying to do.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2